# Can't start postgresql on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Abandoning linuxbrew, installed postgresql using apt instead. Now I get this error:

```
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main -l logfile start
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

I tried running as superuser:

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main -l logfile start
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

I don't understand what user I should be logged in as.

### Original post:

I've brew installed postgresql, but having trouble starting it:

```
$ brew services start postgresql
sh: 1: list: not found
Error: Failure while executing:  load -w /home/me/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

The .plist file exists. Not sure what this error means! Same thing happens when running the command as root.

Comment: Looks like an error of the brew formular. LaunchAgent and `.plist` are imho macOS specific. Why do you use `brew` instead of the offical postgres package source for `apt`?

Comment: Great question, I am a total noob to postgresql and am just following some online tutorials. Now trying the install via apt, will report back!

Comment: OK, now I'm getting a new error, see update above...

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks @t.niese

Answer (score 4):

Oho! Figured it out, thanks to [this thread.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166275/pg-ctl-wont-start-postgres) In Ubuntu, use this command to start postgresql:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```